# Android Room embedded relationship query results

Tags: android, android-room, android-room-relation, android-room-embedded

I am currently trying to get results from a query of nested relationships in Room. Here Are my classes/database entities involved:

```
@Entity
data class PrayerRequestEntity(
    var title: String,
    var details: String,
    var category: String,
    var isAnswered: Boolean,
    var prayerCount: Int,
    var dateCreated: Date,
    var dateUpdated: Date
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var prayerRequestId: Int = 0
}

@Entity
data class PrayerPlanEntity(
    var title: String,
    var sessionCount: Int,
    var dateCreated: Date,
    var dateUpdated: Date
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var planId: Int = 0
}


@Entity(primaryKeys = ["planId", "prayerRequestId"])
data class PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity(
    val planId: Int,
    val prayerRequestId: Int
)
```

I am trying to get a list of PrayerPlanEtities along with the PrayerRequestEntities associated with each and have no problem using the following return:

```
data class PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin(
    @Embedded
    val prayerPlan: PrayerPlanEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "planId",
        entityColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val prayers: List<PrayerPlanEntity>
)
```

I need to also query the relationships of PrayerRequestEntity in that same query so Imodify the aforementioned class like so:

```
data class PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin(
    @Embedded
    val prayerPlan: PrayerPlanEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "planId",
        entityColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val prayers: List<PrayerRequestJoin>
)
```

PrayerRequestJoin is a previous relationship I created which works perfectly fine on it own and looks like so:

```
data class PrayerRequestJoin(
    @Embedded
    val prayerRequest: PrayerRequestEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        entityColumn = "prayerRequestCategoryId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val category: PrayerRequestCategoryEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        entityColumn = "photoId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val photos: List<PhotoEntity>,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        entityColumn = "noteId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val notes: List<NoteEntity>
)
```

But now I am getting two build errors an Android Studio:

error: constructor PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin in class PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin cannot be applied to given types;
_item = new PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin();
^
required: PrayerPlanEntity,List
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

and also:

error: prayerPlan has private access in PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin
_item.prayerPlan = _tmpPrayerPlan;

Can anyone provide some insight on what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your issue is with the @Query's rather than with the relationships.

Upon closer inspection the messages shows java code e.g. termination with `;`'s.

Therefore the issue is within the generated java and it would appear (from creating a working example) that the issue is in the code underlying the class or classes annotated with @Dao

- i.e. `_item` does not appear in the java for the class annotated with `@Database`. Whilst _item = new .... appears for each @Query annotated function. e.g.
- for a Query using `SELECT * FROM PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity` then the code includes `_item = new PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity(_tmpPlanId,_tmpPrayerRequestId);`
- for a Query using `"SELECT * FROM prayerRequestEntity"` then the code includes `_item = new PrayerRequestJoin(_tmpPrayerRequest,_tmpCategory_1,_tmpPhotosCollection_1,_tmpNotesCollection_1);`

As can be seen these are used to build the final result. The first example being the closest from the working example but there is no issue.

As such I believe that the issue is not with the relationships (working example runs OK) but the issue is with the @Query annotated functions.

I would suggest commenting them all out and adding each until you find the culprit.

**The working example**

Note that this example introduces/uses some shortcuts so the code differs a little.

- the code is run on the main thread so uses .allowMainThreadQueries
- Long's are used instead of Ints for id's (they should really always be longs as they can be signed 64 bit)
- Autogenerate has not been used for classes that have been guessed such as NoteEntity (autogenerate (which equates to AUTOINCREMENT) is actually not recommended by SQLite themselves *The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.* https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)
- TypeConverters have been avoided

The code:-

**NoteEntity** made up just to test, so very simple

```
@Entity
data class NoteEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var noteId: Long? = null,
    var noteText: String = ""
)
```

**PhotoEntity** made up ....

```
@Entity
data class PhotoEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var photoId: Long? = null,
    var photoImage: String = "unknown"
)
```

**PrayerPlanEntity**

```
@Entity
data class PrayerPlanEntity(
    var title: String,
    var sessionCount: Int,
    var dateCreated: String, /* changed for brevity */
    var dateUpdated: String /* changed for brevity */
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var planId: Long = 0
}
```

**PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity**

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["planId", "prayerRequestId"])
data class PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity(
    val planId: Long,
    val prayerRequestId: Long
)
```

**PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin** assume the 2nd is as it is now

```
data class PrayerPlanPrayerRequestsJoin(

    /*
    @Embedded
    val prayerPlan: PrayerPlanEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "planId",
        entityColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val prayers: List<PrayerPlanEntity>
    */

    @Embedded
    val prayerPlan: PrayerPlanEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "planId",
        entityColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val prayers: List<PrayerRequestJoin>
)
```

**PrayerRequestCategoryEntity** made up ....

```
@Entity
data class PrayerRequestCategoryEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var prayerRequestCategoryId: Long? = null,
    var categoryName: String
)
```

**PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity** made up ....

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["prayerRequestId", "prayerRequestCategoryId"])
data class PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity(

    val prayerRequestId: Long,
    val prayerRequestCategoryId: Long
)
```

**PrayerRequestEntity**

```
@Entity
data class PrayerRequestEntity(
    var title: String,
    var details: String,
    var category: String,
    var isAnswered: Boolean,
    var prayerCount: Int,
    var dateCreated: String, /* changed for brevity */
    var dateUpdated: String /* changed for brevity */
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var prayerRequestId: Long = 0
}
```

**PrayerRequestJoin**

```
data class PrayerRequestJoin(
    @Embedded
    val prayerRequest: PrayerRequestEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        entityColumn = "prayerRequestCategoryId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val category: PrayerRequestCategoryEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        entityColumn = "photoId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val photos: List<PhotoEntity>,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "prayerRequestId",
        entityColumn = "noteId",
        associateBy = Junction(PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity::class)
    )
    val notes: List<NoteEntity>
)
```

**PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity** made up

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["prayerRequestId", "noteId"])
data class PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity(
    val prayerRequestId: Long,
    val noteId: Long
)
```

**PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity** made up ....

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["prayerRequestId", "photoId"])
data class PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity(
    val prayerRequestId: Long,
    val photoId: Long
)
```

**AllDAO** made up

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(photoEntity: PhotoEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(noteEntity: NoteEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(prayerPlanEntity: PrayerPlanEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict =  OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(prayerRequestCategoryEntity: PrayerRequestCategoryEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(prayerRequestEntity: PrayerRequestEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(prayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity: PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(prayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity: PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(prayerRequestNoteJoinEntity: PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(prayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity: PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM prayerRequestEntity")
    abstract fun getAllPrayerRequests(): List<PrayerRequestEntity>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM prayerPlanEntity")
    abstract fun getAllPrayerPlans(): List<PrayerPlanEntity>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity")
    abstract fun getAllPrayerPlanRequestJoins(): List<PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM prayerRequestEntity")
    abstract fun getAllPrayerRequestsWithCategoryNotesAndPhotos(): List<PrayerRequestJoin>

}
```

**TheDatabase** made up

```
@Database(entities = [
    PhotoEntity::class,
    NoteEntity::class,
    PrayerRequestEntity::class,
    PrayerPlanEntity::class,
    PrayerRequestCategoryEntity::class,
    PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity::class,
    PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity::class,
    PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity::class,
    PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity::class]
    , version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAO(): AllDAO

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"prayer.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least an activity to do a simple test of the related data via the ***getAllPrayerRequestsWithCategoryNotesAndPhotos*** query:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAO()

        val n1id = dao.insert(NoteEntity(noteText = "Note1"))
        val n2id = dao.insert(NoteEntity(noteText = "Note2"))
        val n3id = dao.insert(NoteEntity(noteText = "Note3"))

        val photo1id = dao.insert(PhotoEntity(photoImage = "photo1"))
        val photo2id = dao.insert(PhotoEntity(photoImage = "photo2"))
        val photo3id = dao.insert(PhotoEntity(photoImage = "photo3"))

        val pp1id = dao.insert(PrayerPlanEntity(title = "PP01",10,"today","never"))

        val pcat01id = dao.insert(PrayerRequestCategoryEntity(categoryName = "CAT01"))
        val pcat02id = dao.insert(PrayerRequestCategoryEntity(categoryName = "CAT02"))
        val pcat03id = dao.insert(PrayerRequestCategoryEntity(categoryName = "CAT03"))

        val pr01id =dao.insert(PrayerRequestEntity("PR01","details01","cat01",false,10,"today","never"))

        dao.insert(prayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity = PrayerPlanPrayerRequestJoinEntity(prayerRequestId = pr01id, planId = pp1id))

        dao.insert(PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity(pr01id,photo1id))
        dao.insert(PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity(pr01id,photo2id))
        dao.insert(PrayerRequestPhotoJoinEntity(pr01id,photo3id))
        dao.insert(PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity(pr01id,n1id))
        dao.insert(PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity(pr01id,n2id))
        dao.insert(PrayerRequestNoteJoinEntity(pr01id,n3id))
        dao.insert(PrayerRequestCategoryJoinEntity(pr01id,pcat01id))

        /* Extract the Data and output to the log */ 
        for (prj: PrayerRequestJoin in dao.getAllPrayerRequestsWithCategoryNotesAndPhotos()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Prayer Request = ${prj.prayerRequest.details} \n\tRequestCategory = ${prj.category.categoryName} ID is ${prj.category.prayerRequestCategoryId}")
            for (photos: PhotoEntity in prj.photos) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","\tPhoto = ${photos.photoImage} ID = ${photos.photoId}")
            }
            for (notes: NoteEntity in prj.notes) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","\tNote = ${notes.noteText} ID = ${notes.noteId}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the **result** from the Log:-

```
2022-03-24 12:52:35.758 D/DBINFO: Prayer Request = details01 
        RequestCategory = CAT01 ID is 1
2022-03-24 12:52:35.758 D/DBINFO:   Photo = photo1 ID = 1
2022-03-24 12:52:35.758 D/DBINFO:   Photo = photo2 ID = 2
2022-03-24 12:52:35.758 D/DBINFO:   Photo = photo3 ID = 3
2022-03-24 12:52:35.758 D/DBINFO:   Note = Note2 ID = 2
2022-03-24 12:52:35.759 D/DBINFO:   Note = Note3 ID = 3
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by using specific entity declarations. Was trying to use a variation of the following example: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships

Comment: @Martin Read the links e.g. `entity = Lesson::class, /* NOTE Lesson  NOT LessonWithTeacher (not a table) */` in the `@Relation` annotation (from 1st link)

Comment: I did read the link. I am not sure that applies because I am referring to an actual table in the @Relation annotation. I am using junction tables to link my entities

Comment: @Martin had a closer look and untangled the relationships so changed the answer accordingly. In short look at the `@Dao's`, the relationships appear fine.

Comment: This was a very informed and detailed answer and I appreciate it. I am looking through my Dao now to see if I can narrow down the issue and will update accordingly. Thanks so much.